# Lost system tray on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, system-tray

I am new on this platform. Yesterday I have installed Kubuntu 14.04 on my Laptop throwing Windows 8.1. All are well. But suddenly I cut system tray icon. Now I can not see volume icon, internet icon etc. Total system tray gone. Please suggest me how can I return back system tray. I search in google mamy sites, But I have not get the correct way/answer. I missed too much system tray.

Answer (score 0):

On the far-right of the panel, there is a button with a bubble-shaped icon on it. If you hover over it, a little box reading "Panel Tool Box" will appear.

- Click the button to bring up the toolbox.
- Click the "Add Widgets..." button.
- In the "Enter search term.." text box type "system tray".
- Click-and-drag the system tray onto the panel.